# I can't install JDK7 on Ubuntu 16.04 Download Failed

Tags: java, oracle, ubuntu, java-7

I'm trying to install jdk7 on a my Ubuntu 16.04 machine, here are the commands that I executed:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

The last one returned Download Failed error and was not able to install the package.

Error Screenshot

[image: Error Screenshot]

When I did some digging I found that Oracle no longer provide JDK7 download link on their official site.

If someone has figured out a way to install it please help !

Comment: A) try askUbuntu.com b) you can always install open-jdk instead of the Oracle one

Comment: I think JDK 7 is no longer supported. Why don't you install JDK 8?

Comment: Thanks but the software that I want to install later was not tested on open-jdk so I may go through some error later on I'm looking for a way to install the Oracle jdk7.

Comment: Your software should run using JDK 8, by the way

Answer (score 0):

You should restart your machine and then again try installing.

Or

Try openjdk as

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

openjdk is an open source alternative to oracles jdk. And it should be much preferred on an open source OS like ubuntu

Comment: I'm trying ti install [Axelor business suite](http://www.axelor.com/community/downloads/) wich was only tested on Oracle jdk. If I can't find a way to install the Oracle one I'll go with open-jdk,

Answer (score 0):

Ok, since the binaries are not longer available you will have to download
it manually

1) download jdk-7u80-linux-i586.tar.gz or jdk-7u80-linux-x64.tar.gz based on the architecture of your operative system from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase7-521261.html) (you will have to create an oracle account if you dont have one)

2) Move the file that you just downloaded to this directory 
 /var/cache/oracle-jdk7-installer/

3) Finally run the below commands

```
sudo echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-java.list
sudo echo "deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-java.list
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys EEA14886
sudo apt-get update
sudo echo oracle-java7-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | /usr/bin/debconf-set-selections
sudo apt-get -y install oracle-java7-installer
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this(this will install oracle JDK),

First update the apt-get repos

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

Add the java(7 and 8) repo to apt-get

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
```

Again update the apt-get repo

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

Finally install java 7

```
$ sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but if read my quest what I need is jdk7 cuz later I want to install a software that was only tested on jdk7 so I'm not sure if it'll work jdk8.

Comment: $ sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer